# Enable ScrollView to bounces content

Tags: android, android-widget, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView (and HorizontalScrollView also), with some content on then.

I need to enable these views to bounces the content if the user try to pass beyond the limit of the scrollable content. How I do that?

Comment: By bounce do you mean overscroll or something more / else?

Comment: Its API level 9 but try: [ScrollView.setOverScrollMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode(int))

Comment: Well, this only show a "light" indicator, but should works for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In API Level 9 there is [ScrollView.setOverScrollMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techhui.com/group/android/forum/topics/support-bounce-property-for this guy seems to have made a custom horizontalscrollview that has the bouncing behavior.

Comment: This is something more like this, but I will have a lot of work to adapt this class, thanks anyway